# Does a master Jenkins keep track of a dynamic job created on a slave node?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-build-flow

Amidst a Jenkins job build, using a Groovy script, we can create new jobs dynamically. More on [this](https://medium.com/@ycrnet/create-a-jenkins-job-with-a-groovy-script-e026f4d7ce0b).

We have a one-master-and-n-slave-nodes architecture.

---

We create any Jenkins job (say `some-pipeline-job`) that gets configured on the master Jenkins **obviously**.

On triggering the build of this job (`some-pipeline-job`), the build can run on any slave node.

---

**Consequences:**

1) This job (`some-pipeline-job`) build creates a workspace for each build that can run on any slave node

2) This job (`some-pipeline-job`) has the Groovy code to create a new dynamic job (say `job23`) in runtime, amidst its build

---

**Goal:**

Disk management of workspaces of any job build across slave nodes, using a second step mentioned in this [procedure](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/215549798-Best-Strategy-for-Disk-Space-Management-Clean-Up-Old-Builds), based on some criteria like numberOfDaysOld builds, etc...

---

1)

Can that second step mentioned in [cloudbees-support](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/215549798-Best-Strategy-for-Disk-Space-Management-Clean-Up-Old-Builds) take care of cleaning workspaces for all the builds of specific job (`some-pipeline-job`) run across multiple slave Jenkins nodes?

2)

Does the master Jenkins have information about this dynamic job (`job23`) created by `some-pipeline-job`, at runtime? How can I ensure that a dynamic job gets tracked (configured) in the master Jenkins?

3)

If yes, can that second step mentioned in [cloudbees-support](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/215549798-Best-Strategy-for-Disk-Space-Management-Clean-Up-Old-Builds) take care of cleaning workspace of `job23` build?

Answer (score 1):

There are several strategies to clean workspaces. The easiest would be to use the WipeWorkspace extension for the checkout step.

```
checkout([
   $class: 'GitSCM',
   branches: scm.branches,
   extensions: scm.extensions + [[$class: 'WipeWorkspace']],
   userRemoteConfigs: scm.userRemoteConfigs
])
```

You seem to need something more elaborate. You can list jenkins slaves with `hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves`

What I would do is schedule a pipeline job, add the following functions to it

```
@NonCPS
def onlineSlaves() {
    def slaves = []
    hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves.each {
        try {
            def computer = it.computer
            if (!computer.isOffline()) {
                slaves << it.name
            }
        } catch (error) {
            println error
        }
    }
    return slaves
}

// Run a command on each slave in series
def shAllSlaves(unixCmdLine) {
    onlineSlaves().each {
        try {
            node(it) {
                if (isUnix()) {
                    sh "${unixCmdLine}"
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            println error
        }
    }
}
```

and execute a sh command like find to delete old folders.

```
script {
    def numberOfDaysOld = 10
    shAllSlaves "find /path/to/base/dir/* -type d -ctime +${numberOfDaysOld } -exec rm -rf {} \;"
}
```

Comment: Why are we not able to manage cleanup workspaces of slave nodes, sitting in master Jenkins?